# LEGO turing machine using Rascal

Tags: nxt, mindstorms

I followed the instructions on [LEGO Turing Machine](http://www.legoturingmachine.org/) and succeeded to build it. Next I've tried and failed to program it using NXT Mindstorm GUI. The site mentions a [Rascal](http://www.rascal-mpl.org/) framework, but it doesn't mention how to install it onto the NXT.

I'm not so keen using Rascal, any other well documented framework will do. 
Any suggestions ?

I'm using **NXT 2.0**

Comment: Rascal is a meta-language, a language to write languages in. Have you had a look at the repository https://github.com/DavyLandman/TuringLEGO/blob/master/BitFlipper.nxc Maybe one can load nxc files onto the nxt. Also you can try asking the repository owner via email.

Comment: Right, I'll check the BitFlipper. Sending the owner an email was my first action, thank you for commenting !

Comment: Actually, you can't *build* a turing machine, as it require an infinite tape.

Comment: "Alan Turing's original model has an infinite tape, but LEGO had a slight problem supplying infinite bricks.", from (http://www.legoturingmachine.org/). Even though it serves as an awesome model.